# How to transfer data from table in one region to another region in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a use case where data is getting generated regularly in us-cental1 region and I want to copy that data to a table in US region (multi region) as regular intervals.
Is there a solution for it in BigQuery?